# Make YAxis match ticks in Microsoft.Chart

Tags: c#, .net, charts

I am sure there is a way to do this. I have been looking for a while an just haven't found out. I have major and minor ticks defined in my chart but the values on the LH side of the Y Axis does not match the lines (every 20) in the chart. How can I make the values match the lines?

[image]

**EDIT**
Here are the lines of code that creates the values. These were created in Designer through editing the ChartAreas collection.

```
        chartArea1.AxisX.MajorGrid.Interval = 20D;
        chartArea1.AxisX.MajorTickMark.Interval = 10D;
        chartArea1.AxisX.Maximum = 50D;
        chartArea1.AxisX.Minimum = 0D;
        chartArea1.AxisX2.Maximum = 50D;
        chartArea1.AxisX2.Minimum = 0D;
        chartArea1.AxisY.MajorGrid.Interval = 20D;
        chartArea1.AxisY.Maximum = 420D;
        chartArea1.AxisY.Minimum = 300D;
        chartArea1.AxisY.MinorGrid.Interval = 10D;
        chartArea1.AxisY2.Maximum = 420D;
        chartArea1.AxisY2.Minimum = 300D;
        chartArea1.Name = "ChartArea1";
        this.chart1.ChartAreas.Add(chartArea1);
        legend1.Name = "Legend1";
        this.chart1.Legends.Add(legend1);
        this.chart1.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(12, 27);
        this.chart1.Name = "chart1";
        series1.ChartArea = "ChartArea1";
        series1.ChartType = System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting.SeriesChartType.Point;
        series1.IsValueShownAsLabel = true;
        series1.Legend = "Legend1";
        series1.Name = "TempHistory";
        series2.ChartArea = "ChartArea1";
        series2.ChartType = System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting.SeriesChartType.Line;
        series2.Legend = "Legend1";
        series2.Name = "LowerLimit";
        series3.ChartArea = "ChartArea1";
        series3.ChartType = System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting.SeriesChartType.Line;
        series3.Legend = "Legend1";
        series3.Name = "UpperLimit";
        this.chart1.Series.Add(series1);
        this.chart1.Series.Add(series2);
        this.chart1.Series.Add(series3);
        this.chart1.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(1326, 186);
        this.chart1.TabIndex = 53;
        this.chart1.Text = "chart1";
```

Comment: You need to __show the code__ that sets Interval, Grid and Ticks and maybe Min and Max!

Answer (score 0):

chartArea1.AxisY.Interval needs to equal chartArea1.AxisX.MajorGrid.Interval